# How can I store the number 146,660,670,200 in a SQL table with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Up until now the maximum number I wanted to store is: 1,466,606,702.

I have been using in ASP.Net:

```
public int WordId { get; set; }
```

and in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Word] (
   [WordId]        INT            NOT NULL,
```

Now I need to store a larger number which is 100 times bigger.

Can someone tell me what would be the best datatypes to use for this in SQL Server and ASP.Net?  Also this will be my primary key value. Will there be any problems using a larger number for the primary key?

Answer (score 3):

Use [BIGINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187745.aspx). Range from `-2^63` to `2^63-1`

`BIGINT` is the equivalent of `Int64` (8 bytes) (which is `long` in C#).

Comment: Thank you. Do you think there would be any issues / differences with using that as a key value instead of an INT?

Comment: No. Perfectly fine to use as a key column

Comment: @SamanthaJ Will occupy more bytes when compared to INT other then that it is perfectly fine